# Nifi cluster's second node fails to start again during unexpected shutdown

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, apache-nifi

I have deployed a nifi cluster in k8 using the following yaml file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: nifi
  namespace: release
  labels:
    app: nifi
    release: nifi
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nifi
      release: nifi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nifi
        release: nifi
      annotations:
        security.alpha.kubernetes.io/sysctls: net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=10000 65000
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: bootstrap-conf
          configMap:
            name: nifi-config
            items:
              - key: bootstrap.conf
                path: bootstrap.conf
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: nifi-properties
          configMap:
            name: nifi-config
            items:
              - key: nifi.properties
                path: nifi.temp
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: authorizers-temp
          configMap:
            name: nifi-config
            items:
              - key: authorizers.xml
                path: authorizers.temp
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: bootstrap-notification-services-xml
          configMap:
            name: nifi-config
            items:
              - key: bootstrap-notification-services.xml
                path: bootstrap-notification-services.xml
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: login-identity-providers-ldap-xml
          configMap:
            name: nifi-config
            items:
              - key: login-identity-providers-ldap.xml
                path: login-identity-providers-ldap.xml
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: state-management-xml
          configMap:
            name: nifi-config
            items:
              - key: state-management.xml
                path: state-management.xml
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: zookeeper-properties
          configMap:
            name: nifi-config
            items:
              - key: zookeeper.properties
                path: zookeeper.properties
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: flow-content
          configMap:
            name: nifi-config
            items:
              - key: flow.xml
                path: flow.xml
            defaultMode: 420
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: apache/nifi:latest
          command:
            - bash
            - '-ce'
            - >
              prop_replace () {
                target_file=${NIFI_HOME}/conf/${3:-nifi.properties}
                echo "updating ${1} in ${target_file}"
                if egrep "^${1}=" ${target_file} &> /dev/null; then
                  sed -i -e "s|^$1=.*$|$1=$2|"  ${target_file}
                else
                  echo ${1}=${2} >> ${target_file}
                fi
              }

              mkdir -p ${NIFI_HOME}/config-data/conf

              FQDN=$(hostname -f)


              cat "${NIFI_HOME}/conf/nifi.temp" >
              "${NIFI_HOME}/conf/nifi.properties"

              bin/nifi.sh set-single-user-credentials username changemechangeme

              if ! test -f /opt/nifi/data/flow.xml.gz && test -f
              /opt/nifi/data/flow.xml; then
                gzip /opt/nifi/data/flow.xml
              fi

              prop_replace nifi.remote.input.host ${FQDN}

              prop_replace nifi.cluster.node.address ${FQDN}

              prop_replace nifi.zookeeper.connect.string
              ${NIFI_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_STRING}

              prop_replace nifi.web.http.host ${FQDN}

  

              if [ ! -r "${NIFI_HOME}/conf/nifi-cert.pem" ]

              then
                /opt/nifi/nifi-toolkit-current/bin/tls-toolkit.sh standalone \
                  -n 'nifi-nifi-0.nifi-nifi-headless.release.svc.cluster.local' \
                  -C 'CN=admin, OU=NIFI' \
                  -o "${NIFI_HOME}/conf/" \
                  -P changeMe \
                  -S changeMe \
                  --nifiPropertiesFile /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
              fi


              for f in "${NIFI_HOME}/conf/authorizers.xml"
              "${NIFI_HOME}/conf/login-identity-providers.xml"
              ${NIFI_HOME}/conf/nifi.properties

              do
                echo === $f ===
                cat $f
              done

              echo === end of files ===


              function prop () {
                target_file=${NIFI_HOME}/conf/nifi.properties
                egrep "^${1}=" ${target_file} | cut -d'=' -f2
              }


              function offloadNode() {
                  FQDN=$(hostname -f)
                  echo "disconnecting node '$FQDN'"
                  baseUrl=https://${FQDN}:8443

                  echo "keystoreType=$(prop nifi.security.keystoreType)" > secure.properties
                  echo "keystore=$(prop nifi.security.keystore)" >> secure.properties
                  echo "keystorePasswd=$(prop nifi.security.keystorePasswd)" >> secure.properties
                  echo "truststoreType=$(prop nifi.security.truststoreType)" >> secure.properties
                  echo "truststore=$(prop nifi.security.truststore)" >> secure.properties
                  echo "truststorePasswd=$(prop nifi.security.truststorePasswd)" >> secure.properties
                  echo "proxiedEntity=CN=admin, OU=NIFI" >> secure.properties
                 
                  secureArgs="-p secure.properties"

                  echo baseUrl ${baseUrl}
                  echo "gracefully disconnecting node '$FQDN' from cluster"
                  ${NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME}/bin/cli.sh nifi get-nodes -ot json -u ${baseUrl} ${secureArgs} > nodes.json
                  nnid=$(jq --arg FQDN "$FQDN" '.cluster.nodes[] | select(.address==$FQDN) | .nodeId' nodes.json)
                  echo "disconnecting node ${nnid}"
                  ${NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME}/bin/cli.sh nifi disconnect-node -nnid $nnid -u ${baseUrl} ${secureArgs}
                  echo ""
                  echo "get a connected node"
                  connectedNode=$(jq -r 'first(.cluster.nodes|=sort_by(.address)| .cluster.nodes[] | select(.status=="CONNECTED")) | .address' nodes.json)
                  baseUrl=https://${connectedNode}:8443
                  echo baseUrl ${baseUrl}
                  echo ""
                  echo "wait until node has state 'DISCONNECTED'"
                  while [[ "${node_state}" != "DISCONNECTED" ]]; do
                      sleep 1
                      ${NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME}/bin/cli.sh nifi get-nodes -ot json -u ${baseUrl} ${secureArgs} > nodes.json
                      node_state=$(jq -r --arg FQDN "$FQDN" '.cluster.nodes[] | select(.address==$FQDN) | .status' nodes.json)
                      echo "state is '${node_state}'"
                  done
                  echo ""
                  echo "node '${nnid}' was disconnected"
                  echo "offloading node"
                  ${NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME}/bin/cli.sh nifi offload-node -nnid $nnid -u ${baseUrl} ${secureArgs}
                  echo ""
                  echo "wait until node has state 'OFFLOADED'"
                  while [[ "${node_state}" != "OFFLOADED" ]]; do
                      sleep 1
                      ${NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME}/bin/cli.sh nifi get-nodes -ot json -u ${baseUrl} ${secureArgs} > nodes.json
                      node_state=$(jq -r --arg FQDN "$FQDN" '.cluster.nodes[] | select(.address==$FQDN) | .status' nodes.json)
                      echo "state is '${node_state}'"
                  done
              }


              deleteNode() {
                  echo "deleting node"
                  ${NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME}/bin/cli.sh nifi delete-node -nnid ${nnid} -u ${baseUrl} ${secureArgs}
                  echo "node deleted"
              }


              executeTrap() {
                 echo Received trapped signal, beginning shutdown...;
                 ./bin/nifi.sh stop;
                 exit 0;
              }


              trap executeTrap TERM HUP INT;

              trap ":" EXIT


              exec bin/nifi.sh run & nifi_pid="$!"

              echo NiFi running with PID ${nifi_pid}.

              wait ${nifi_pid}
          ports:
            - name: https
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: cluster
              containerPort: 6007
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: NIFI_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_STRING
              value: nifi-zookeeper:2181
            - name: NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_HOST
              value: 0.0.0.0
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: my-logs
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
            - name: my-data
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/data
            - name: my-auth-conf
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/auth-conf/
            - name: my-config-data
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/config-data
            - name: my-flowfile-repository
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/flowfile_repository
            - name: my-content-repository
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/content_repository
            - name: my-provenance-repository
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/provenance_repository
            - name: my-nifi-input
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi_input
            - name: my-nifi-output
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi_output
            - name: my-nifi-release-config
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi_release_config
            - name: bootstrap-conf
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/bootstrap.conf
              subPath: bootstrap.conf
            - name: nifi-properties
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.temp
              subPath: nifi.temp
            - name: authorizers-temp
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/authorizers.temp
              subPath: authorizers.temp
            - name: bootstrap-notification-services-xml
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/bootstrap-notification-services.xml
              subPath: bootstrap-notification-services.xml
            - name: login-identity-providers-ldap-xml
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/login-identity-providers-ldap.xml
              subPath: login-identity-providers-ldap.xml
            - name: state-management-xml
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/state-management.xml
              subPath: state-management.xml
            - name: zookeeper-properties
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/zookeeper.properties
              subPath: zookeeper.properties
            - name: flow-content
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/data/flow.xml
              subPath: flow.xml
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 8443
            initialDelaySeconds: 90
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 60
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        - name: app-log
          image: busybox:1.32.0
          args:
            - /bin/sh
            - '-c'
            - trap "exit 0" TERM; tail -n+1 -F /var/log/nifi-app.log & wait $!
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 50Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 10m
              memory: 10Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: my-logs
              mountPath: /var/log
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        - name: bootstrap-log
          image: busybox:1.32.0
          args:
            - /bin/sh
            - '-c'
            - >-
              trap "exit 0" TERM; tail -n+1 -F /var/log/nifi-bootstrap.log &
              wait $!
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 50Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 10m
              memory: 10Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: my-logs
              mountPath: /var/log
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        - name: user-log
          image: busybox:1.32.0
          args:
            - /bin/sh
            - '-c'
            - trap "exit 0" TERM; tail -n+1 -F /var/log/nifi-user.log & wait $!
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 50Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 10m
              memory: 10Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: my-logs
              mountPath: /var/log
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      serviceAccountName: default
      serviceAccount: default
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 1
              podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchExpressions:
                    - key: app
                      operator: In
                      values:
                        - nifi
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: my-logs
        namespace: release
      spec:
        storageClassName: nifi-storage
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 5Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: my-config-data
        namespace: release
      spec:
        storageClassName: nifi-storage
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 100Mi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: my-data
        namespace: release
      spec:
        storageClassName: nifi-storage
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: my-flowfile-repository
        namespace: release
      spec:
        storageClassName: nifi-storage
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: my-content-repository
        namespace: release
      spec:
        storageClassName: nifi-storage
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: my-provenance-repository
        namespace: release
      spec:
        storageClassName: nifi-storage
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: my-auth-conf
        namespace: release
      spec:
        storageClassName: nifi-storage
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 100Mi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: my-nifi-input
        namespace: release
      spec:
        storageClassName: nifi-storage
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: my-nifi-output
        namespace: release
      spec:
        storageClassName: nifi-storage
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: my-nifi-release-config
        namespace: release
      spec:
        storageClassName: nifi-storage
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 100Mi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
  serviceName: nifi-headless
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      partition: 0
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
```

As you can see I have several local volumes that I am binding, so that my data persists even if the entire cluster fails. During testing, after feeding the flow some data and shutting down the k8 cluster, on restart I get the following issue.

```
2022-12-28 15:49:41,632 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr Failed to start web server: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiWebApiSecurityConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'securityFilterChain' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.nifi.web.security.configuration.JwtAuthenticationSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'idpUserGroupService' defined in class path resource [nifi-administration-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'idpTransactionBuilder' while setting bean property 'transactionBuilder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'idpTransactionBuilder' defined in class path resource [nifi-administration-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'idpDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'idpDataSource': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database may be already in use: "/opt/nifi/data/database_repository/nifi-identity-providers.mv.db". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-214]
2022-12-28 15:49:41,633 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr Shutting down...
```

Nifi-0 works, but nifi-1 keeps failing and going through multiple restarts. I'm assuming from the logs, the issue is that the database is still in use which is why the second node fails. I want to avoid deleting the contents of the database repository, so any other solutions are much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: did you figure this out? facing a similar issue.

Comment: Not exactly, I shifted towards using nifikop operator with cstore volumes and a nifi registry which you will need to manually configure. This solved the restart problem. I'm not sure how you set up your cluster, but my nifi cluster was deployed to a multi-node k8s cluster and if a k8 node failed permanently, you will run into similar issues.